# Way around Double substitution from Symbolab

Tags: calculus, integration

I found this double substitution from  [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20x%5E%7B3%7De%5E%7Bx%5E2%7Ddx)  my question is, is there a method that involves not doing a double u-substitution.  My thoughts were that doing integration by parts, and setting $u= e^{x^2}\ \ \text{and}\ \ v=x^3.$

## Problem

$$\int x^3e^{x^2}dx$$

## My Question

Is there another way in doing the problem? I find the double substitution cumbersome?

Comment: To evaluate $\int x^3e^{x^2}dx$ with integration by parts, you want to choose $u,\,v$ so $uv^\prime$, as opposed to $uv$, is equal to $x^3e^{x^2}$. By the way, please edit your question so readers don't have to follow your link to see which problem is to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $u=\frac12x^2,\,v=e^{x^2}$ we have $\int uv^\prime dx=\frac12x^2e^{x^2}-\int xe^{x^2}dx=\frac12(x^2-1)e^{x^2}+C$. I'll leave it to the reader to decide whether this uses substitution or inspection.

Comment: New technique more for me thanks. +1

Comment: Thanks sneaky, how did you know to do that. I did the following $\int u \ dv = uv- \int v \ du$ So my question in regards to your answer is that are you allowed to break apart the integral where in my case $u=\frac{1}2x^2\ \text{and} \ dv = 2xe^{x^2}dx$, so long as when $u, \text{and} dv$ are multiplied together give you back the original integrand. I know now that this was done by inspection and not by substitution.